# Advanced PHP sorting

Tags: php, sorting

I understand how to used basic sorting with standard php functions such as natsort() and even some custom sorting using usort().  My question is how to get the natural sort outcome when there are many forms of variables.

Example:

```
$test = array('3,000 Numeral', '2 A', '2 A+', '2 B', '2 C', '3 A', '3 B', '4 A', '4 A+', '4 B', 'A', 'A+', 'B', 'C');
```

using usort or natsort we end up with the array outputting numeric values first and alphanumeric last.  Worse the sort functions treat the comma separated numeric values as if the numbers after the comma do not exist.  We end up with:

```
array('2 A', '2 A+', '2 B', '2 C', '3 A', '3 B', '3,000 Numeral', '4 A', '4 A+', '4 B', 'A', 'A+', 'B', 'C')
```

So I guess my question is how to use advanced sorting to deal with multiple levels of sort logic to end up with the natural progression.  Something like:

```
array('A', 'A+', 'B', 'C', '2 A', '2 A+', '2 B', '2 C', '3 A', '3 B', '4 A', '4 A+', '4 B', '3,000 Numeral')
```

Comment: You said it, usort(). If you can explain how something should be sorted then you can implement it with usort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not tested nor complete suggestion:

Get each letter of the word, if it is numeric put it in an `array`:

`$array[] = $letter`

else, subtract `A` from it and put the result in the `array`:

`$array[] = ord($letter) - ord('A')`

You'll have a number for a number, and a number representing the distance from 'A' for every letter.

I suppose you'll also have to do some other checks for symbols and spaces also.